# Can't figure out what happened to file, and can't recreate it in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class (let's call it A.java) that references another class (let's call it B.java), and today I noticed that the B.java object was having an error in the A.java file. Hovering over the error, I noticed that eclipse doesn't seem to think B.java exists anymore because it wants me to create a B.java class, as if it's not there. So I go check the package that should contain B.java--it's not there. I figured maybe I deleted it without knowing, but upon looking at the deleted files history for this package, I see that no files have ever been deleted. So I decide to remake A.java in the package where it should be, but I am unable to create it. When attempting to remake B.java, I receive the error:

"type with same name but different case exists"

What happened, and how can I either find B.java or remake the class?

**Note: There is no lowercase b.java file, this is clearly a different issue

Comment: Try refreshing (menu action) the project that should have class B.  It sounds like it's on the filesystem but not known to Eclipse. This happens when you abnormally terminate Eclipse after creating resources but before Eclipse has a chance to update its metadata

Comment: Thank you! This has never happened to me. Would you mind explaining what happened with eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"type with same name but different case exists" means you probably have a `b.java` file (lower case b).

If the file system you are using is case insensitive you can't have both `B.java` and `b.java` files.

You might need to do a 'Refresh' on the project to get Eclipse to refresh the project contents from the file system. If a project is modified outside of Eclipse it may not see the changes.

Comment: I read the other posts about this. I do not have a b.java file.

Comment: In fact, I've been working with A.java for a long time, and there have been no problems. I have not touched B.java since I've started working on A.java as well.

Comment: Try doing a 'Refresh' on the project to make sure all files are being shown in Eclipse.

Comment: Added info about refresh.